# Core data not working on device but fine on simulator

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectmodel

I am using core data for my application.It works fine on simulator but not retreiving the details on real device.Device is of iOS6.1.This is the code i am using:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) getCurrentMangedContext
{
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"ForceData" withExtension:@"momd"];
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];  

    NSURL *storeURL =  [[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"ForceData.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistantStroreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
    if (![persistantStroreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error])
    {

    }
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init] ;
    [managedContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:persistantStroreCoordinator];
    modelURL = nil;
    return  managedContext;
}
```

This is how i am saving my login details and it is not giving any error.

```
 NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:context];
  [request setEntity:entity];
  NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];
    if (emailString != nil)
    {
       [newManagedObject setValue:emailString forKey:@"email"]; 
    }
    if (genderString != nil)
    {
        [newManagedObject setValue:genderString forKey:@"gender"]; 
    }
    if (fNameString != nil)
    {
        [newManagedObject setValue:fNameString forKey:@"firstName"]; 
    }
    if (lNameString != nil)
    {
        [newManagedObject setValue:lNameString forKey:@"lastName"]; 
    }
   if (userIDString != nil)
    {
        [newManagedObject setValue:userIDString forKey:@"userID"]; 
    }
  NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    // Insert User details to the user DB <--------------------------
```

And this is how i am retrieving:

```
- (User *) getActiveUser 
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self getCurrentMangedContext];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSError *errorFetch = nil;
    NSArray *array = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&errorFetch];
    User *objUser = (User *) [array lastObject];
    NSLog(@"%@",objUser);

    return objUser;
}
```

But i am not getting the user details on device but getting on simulator.anyone faced this same?

Comment: Can you post the output of `NSLog(@"%@",objUser);`. BTW: Please don't prefix your getter methods with `get`. Simply `- (User *)activeUser` - by convention: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html

Comment: What debugging have you done? At least log the errors returned by each method...

Comment: @FlorianMielke thanks for the info.what i am getting in objUser is:<NSManagedObject: 0x1fad7880> (entity: User; id: 0x1facde20 <x-coredata://82F4763C-B9C1-4D27-BE75-F264EB14AF04/User/p1> ; data: <fault>)
2013-12-14 18:31:31.811 ForcePack 1.3[3851:7607] <NSManagedObject: 0x1fad8520> (entity: User; id: 0x1faccb70 <x-coredata://82F4763C-B9C1-4D27-BE75-F264EB14AF04/User/p1> ; data: <fault>)

Comment: I'd suggest that the associated managed object context is no longer available. Can you please try to assign the managed object context to an appropriate property. A managed object can't live without it's managed object context being alive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I'd suggest that ARC releases your `managedObjectContext` after executing the fetch request.

Make sure that you hold a `strong` reference to the appropriate `managedObjectContext` during the whole lifetime of your `managedObject` somewhere in your app (e.g. your  `ApplicationDelegate`). A `NSManagedObject` can't live without it's managedObjectContext. The Core Data project template shows how to do that.

Further information about ARC and strong references: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Thanks a lot dude...this simple thing stole my hours. I tried even with replacing the core data with a new one.:)

Comment: Your welcome. When starting with Core Data I've also stumbled over this some times.